# receiving an array from a WCF service and display it into a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am trying to pupulate a listbox with entries of an object which comes from a wcf service
I basically send a request for a group and I receive an array of groups that match the request. 
however I managed just to display the name of the object rather thna its content.

any idea? I have might missed the obvious but cannot really spot it.

```
        int i = 1;
        GroupServiceClient client = new GroupServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IGroupService");
        www.test.co.uk.User.user User = new www.test.co.uk.User.user();
        www.test.co.uk.programme.programme Group = new www.test.co.uk.programme.programme();
        www.test.co.uk.programme.programme[] Groups = new www.test.co.uk.programme.programme[i];

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        values.Clear();
        client.Open();

        Group.number = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
        client.GetGroups(ref time, Group);


        GroupArrayMessage toReturn = new GroupArrayMessage();
        toReturn.groups = Groups;


        listBox1.ItemsSource = Groups.ToString(); ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = Groups;       // no .ToString()
listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; // should be a Group property
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the function DisplayMember in the listBox1

Comment: Thanks again still nothing, if I reverse back toString it returns back www.test.co.uk.programme.programme[] a character per each line.

Comment: Can you describe "nothing" ?  Maybe you need a ToList() , but certainly not a ToString()

Comment: The listbox remains blank, whereas if I try with wcftestclient I get the list of groups, so I know that the back end is fine.

Comment: Use the Debugger and/or Output Window.

Comment: Thanks again I used the degugger step by step and I discovered that Groups contains nothing, the request is correct but the way I handle the response is not:  www.test.co.uk.programme.programme[] Groups = new www.test.co.uk.programme.programme

Comment: I accept your answer as it is correct as it is, I discovered that the probles is that I have noothing returning! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First 
You can't use Group.ToString() because ItemSource Property of any ItemControl accept only list kind of object

So 
Use

```
listBox1.ItemSource = Groups;
```